# When should weak references be used?

Tags: c#, java, weak-references

I recently came across a piece of Java code with WeakReferences - I had never seen them deployed although I'd come across them when they were introduced. Is this something that should be routinely used or only when one runs into memory problems? If the latter, can they be easily retrofitted or does the code need serious refactoring? Can the average Java (or C#) programmer generally ignore them?

**EDIT** Can any damage be done by over-enthusiastic use of WRs?

Comment: Couple more examples of uses for weak references at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434156/other-uses-of-weak-references

Comment: As far as I know the only danger with WR is that you might actually want a *strong* reference. If your objects start disappearing when you don't want them to you might have gone too far ;)

Comment: You have to know when to use them and how, and in some cases it comes down to similar issues as found in multithreading with locking on data. For instance, it's just wrong to to a (.NET sample): `if (x.IsAlive) { x.Target.ToString(); }` because the object may have been collected in the meantime. You first have to acquire a strong reference and then check if it is still alive: `object t = x.Target; if (t != null) { t.ToString(); }` because as soon as you have re-acquired a strong reference to the object, it will not be collected.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Weak references are all about garbage collection. A *standard* object will not "disappear" until all references to it are severed, this means all the references your various objects have to it have to be removed before garbage collection will consider it garbage.

With a weak reference just because your object is referenced by other objects doesn't necessarily mean it's not garbage. It can still get picked up by GC and get removed from memory.

An example: If I have a bunch of Foo objects in my application I might want to use a Set to keep a central record of all the Foo's I have around. But, when other parts of my application remove a Foo object by deleting all references to it, I don't want the remaining reference my Set holds to that object to keep it from being garbage collected! Really I just want it to disappear from my set. This is where you'd use something like a Weak Set (Java has a WeakHashMap) instead, which uses weak references to its members instead of "strong" references.

If your objects aren't being garbage collected when you want them to then you've made an error in your book keeping, something's still holding a reference that you forgot to remove. Using weak references can ease the pain of such book keeping, since you don't have to worry about them keeping an object "alive" and un-garbage-collected, but you don't *have* to use them.

Answer (score 19):

You use them whenever you want to have a reference to an object without keeping the object alive yourself. This is true for many caching-like features, but also play an important role in event handling, where a subscriber shall not be kept alive by being subscribed to an event.

A small example: A timer event which refreshes some data. Any number of objects can subscribe on the timer in order to get notified, but the bare fact that they subscribed on the timer should not keep them alive. So the timer should have weak references to the objects.

Comment: Using weak references (notably through `WeakHashMap`) can go horribly wrong. For instance, the VM may notice that it can clear the references almost immediately after they are created. This does happen, although usually after the application has been running a while.

Comment: tackline - I'm not sure about 'horribly wrong' - certainly if they are used when they shouldn't be, then the app will fail - but that's a design issue, not anything to do with weak references per-se

Comment: I'm not saying that you should reference an object only throug a weak reference, but rather that you can use those to keep references to objects where it isn't your responsibility to keep them alive. Usually, those objects will be part of a strongly referenced object graph, but when that graph goes out of scope, the weak reference shouldn't hinder the GC to collect those. It's always the same: use the appropriate tools where they fit.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: Weak references should generally only be used in cases where it the objects in question are only useful *because strong references exist to them*. While it's sometimes useful for factory methods to cache weak references for created objects, such behavior should be predicated not upon the cost of creating an object twice and later creating an identical object, but rather upon the potential cost of having multiple references to identical objects *exist simultaneously*.  If code creates creates an object and a weak reference to it and returns the only strong reference...

Comment: ...then the importance of having a later call return the same object would depend upon whether the caller had kept the earlier reference (or given it to anyone else who kept it).  If so, upholding the second condition would require that the earlier object be returned.  If not, then having the first object cease to exist and having code create a new one would uphold that second condition just as well as would having the first object stick around long enough for the code to return it.

Answer (score 10):

> Can any damage be done by
>   over-enthusiastic use of WRs?

Yes it can.

One concern is that weak references make your code more complicated and potentially error prone.  Any code that uses a weak reference needs to deal with the possibility that the reference has been broken each time it uses it.  If you over-use weak references you end up writing lots of extra code.  (You can mitigate this by hiding each weak reference behind a method that takes care of the checking, and re-creates the discarded object on demand.  But this may not necessarily be as simple as that; e.g. if the re-creation process involves network access, you need to cope with the possibility of re-creation failure.)

A second concern is that there are runtime overheads with using weak references.  The obvious costs are those of creating weak references and calling `get` on them.  A less obvious cost is that significant extra work needs to be done each time the GC runs.

A final concern is that if you use a weak references for something that your application is highly likely to need in the future, you may incur the cost of repeatedly recreating it.  If this cost is high (in terms of CPU time, IO bandwidth, network traffic, whatever) your application may perform badly as a result.  You may be better off giving the JVM more memory and not using weak references at all.

Off course, this does not mean you should avoid using weak references entirely.  Just that you need to think carefully.  And probably you should first run a memory profiler on your application to figure out where your memory usage problems stem from.

Answer (score 1):

A good question to ask when considering use of a WeakReference is how one would feel if the weak reference were invalidated the instant no strong references existed to the object.  If that would make the WeakReference less useful, then a WeakReference is probably not the best thing to use.  If that would be an improvement over the non-deterministic invalidation that comes from garbage-collection, then a WeakReference is probably the right choice.